# MouseOver Flicking

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Why is mouse over flickering with these set events?

I have tried the following code

```
const headerTags1 = document.querySelector('h1');
headerTags1.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event){
event.target.style.display = "none";
})
console.log(headerTags1)

const headerTags2 = document.querySelector('h1');
headerTags2.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event){
event.target.style.display = "initial";
})
console.log(headerTags2)
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] to see the issue we can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scott Marcus gave an excellent explanation for the flickering.

As an alternative you could use the opacity-property of the style. But the element would be still clickable.

```js
const headerTags = document.querySelector('h1');

headerTags.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event){
  event.target.style.opacity = 0;
})

headerTags.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event){
  event.target.style.opacity = 1;
})
```

```html
<h1>Now you see me...</h1>
```

Comment: @Jonaahfire See my answer on doing this without JavaScript at all.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because as soon as you hover over an `h1` it hides, and because it's now hidden, you aren't mousing over it anymore and `mouseleave` fires, so it's then shown, but then you are mousing over it, so it hides, and so on.

```js
const headerTags1 = document.querySelector('h1');
headerTags1.addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event){
event.target.style.display = "none";
})
console.log(headerTags1)

const headerTags2 = document.querySelector('h1');
headerTags2.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(event){
event.target.style.display = "initial";
})
console.log(headerTags2)
```

```html
<h1>Now you see me...</h1>
```

This, of course, is not a good design decision in the first place. What are you really trying to accomplish?

**EDIT:**

> Just want to have the button disappear and reappear when it's hovered
>   over or better yet just change colors when it's hovered over...

Then the better approach would be to just use the [CSS `:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) to modify the element' style only while it's being hovered.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title Here</title>
  <style>
    h1:hover { opacity:0; }
    button:hover { color:red; background-color:#ff0; }  
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>Now you see me...</h1>
  <button>Hover Over Me</button>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just  want to have the button disappear and reappear when it's hovered over or better yet just change colors when it's hovered over...

Comment: Ok  Scott I moved the hover option to my navigation, I know this is wrong, but I don't know how to properly set this up...

Comment: const homeNavLink = document.querySelector('.nav a');
homeNavLink.addEventListener('hover', function(event){
h1:hover=color red; 
button:hover=background-color:#ff0; })
@ScottMarcus

Comment: @Jonaahfire No, you misunderstand. **There is no JavaScript needed at all** in my example. Just CSS. You place the CSS inside of a `<style>` element and that element goes in the `<head>` element of the document. No JavaScript. I'll update the answer to show what the full document structure would look like.